# paypal checkout onApprove function

Tags: php, paypal

Hi guys I am using PayPal checkout API to make payments from my site

this is the code i am using to capture products in server side and it works well

```
<?php
require('../ini.php');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$ids = [
  'id' =>     getSetting('paypalLiveKey','return',$con),
  'secret' => getSetting('paypalSecretKey','return',$con)
];


$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
  new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
    $ids['id'],
    $ids['secret']
  )
);


$redirectUrls = (new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls())
    ->setReturnUrl('/include/paypalPHP/payProducts.php')
    ->setCancelUrl('/checkout.php');


$list = new \PayPal\Api\ItemList();


$item = (new \PayPal\Api\Item())
    ->setName('title')
    ->setPrice('100')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity('1');

  $list->addItem($item);


$details = (new \PayPal\Api\Details())
    ->setSubtotal($total )
    ->setTax('0.00')
    ->setShipping('0.00')
    ->setShippingDiscount('0.00');

$amount = (new \PayPal\Api\Amount())
    ->setTotal('100')
    ->setCurrency("USD")
    ->setDetails($details);

$transaction = (new \PayPal\Api\Transaction())
    ->setItemList($list)
    ->setDescription('New Payment from ')
    ->setAmount($amount)
    ->setCustom('site');

$payer = (new \PayPal\Api\Payer())
    ->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$payment = (new \PayPal\Api\Payment())
    ->setTransactions([$transaction])
    ->setIntent('sale')
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setPayer($payer);


try {
  $payment->Create($apiContext);
  // header("location: ".$payment->getApprovalLink());

  echo json_encode([
    'token' => $payment->getToken(),

  ]);
} catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e){
  header('loaction: '.ERROR_PAGE);
  var_dump(json_decode($e->getData()));
}
```

the second code that I am using to make payments

```
<?php
require('../ini.php');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$ids = [
  'id' =>     getSetting('paypalLiveKey','return',$con),
  'secret' => getSetting('paypalSecretKey','return',$con)
];

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
  new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
    $ids['id'],
    $ids['secret']
  )
);


$payment = \PayPal\Api\Payment::get($_POST['paymentID'],$apiContext);

$execution = (new \PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution())
        ->setPayerId($_POST['payerID'])
        ->setTransactions($payment->getTransactions());

try{
    $payment->execute($execution,$apiContext);

    // payment is done

    echo json_encode([
        'id' => $payment->getId()
      ]);

    var_dump($payment->getTransactions()[0]->getCustom());
    var_dump($payment);

}catch(\PayPal\Exeception\PayPalConnectionException $e){
    header('loaction: '.ERROR_PAGE);
    var_dump(json_decode($e->getData()));
}
```

the code I am using in client side to fetch this codes

```
paypal.Buttons({

    // Set up the transaction
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return fetch('/include/paypalPHP/prepareProducts.php', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(data) {
            return data.token;
        });
    },

    // Finalize the transaction
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return fetch('/include/paypalPHP/payProducts.php', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                paymentID: data.paymentID,
                payerID:   data.payerID
            })
        })
    }


}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

now if I clicked on paypal buttons the product item is showed well but the problem is when he click pay on PayPal window no thing is payed i think the problem is with `onApprove` function

any help please

Comment: This code needs to be run and debugged at runtime, so you are best equipped to do that yourself. Look for errors and print everything out at every step so you can find why it's not behaving as expected. On the PHP side you should be using the v2 SDK, https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

Comment: I used the same code without client side ,Just open the page that capture the payment and uncomment this code header("location: ".$payment->getApprovalLink()) and the payment is done well but by using client side code capturing is good but payment does not do anything and no console errors appears

Comment: That's nice, someone still needs to debug it step by step at runtime to find what's actually happening, and that should be you. (Maybe someone else has time to run your code and provide free debugging services; I certainly don't)

Comment: Ok it is ok , but can you tell me the process of paypal checkout I mean first code send your products to paypal and they respond with token then what second code do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with that `setReturnUrl` for some what it should not be the same page as the on approve function post. so you have to change it to something else